# How to generate URLs in a TYPO3 scheduler task for a tt_news record?

Tags: php, typo3, scheduler, tt-news

I am currently writing a scheduler for TYPO3 (4.7.7).

In my task I need some URLs for records from tt_news. I tried to "boot" the frontend as did in "pxa_newstofb" extension but this does not work. Here is my current class that should generate a link to a news record:

```
<?php

abstract class tx_myextension_newshelper {

    /**
     * @var tslib_cObj
     */
    protected $cObj;

    function __construct() {
    }

    /**
     * Creates a URL for the given news
     *
     * @param $news
     * @return string
     */
    public function link($news) {
        // Init frontend
        $this->initTSFE($news['pid']);

        $newsLink = $this->cObj->typoLink_URL(array(
            'no_cache' => false,
            'parameter' => $news['pid'],
            'additionalParams' => '&tx_ttnews[tt_news]=' . $news['uid'],
            'useCacheHash' => true
        ));

        if (substr($newsLink, 0, 7) != 'http://' || substr($newsLink, 0, 8) != 'https://') {
            $newsLink = $this->host($news) . $newsLink;
        }

        return $newsLink;
    }

    public function host($news) {
        return 'http://localhost/';
    }

    /**
     * Initialize frontend
     *
     * @param int $pageUid
     */
    public function initTSFE($pageUid = 1) {

        global $GLOBALS, $TSFE, $TYPO3_CONF_VARS;

        $this->cObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');
        $temp_TTclassName = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_timeTrack');
        $GLOBALS['TT'] = new $temp_TTclassName();
        $GLOBALS['TT']->start();

        $TSFE = new tslib_fe($TYPO3_CONF_VARS, $pageUid, 0, 0);
        $TSFE->connectToDB();
        $TSFE->initFEuser();
        $TSFE->fetch_the_id();
        $TSFE->getPageAndRootline();
        $TSFE->initTemplate();
        $TSFE->forceTemplateParsing = 1;
        $TSFE->getConfigArray();
        $TSFE->initUserGroups();
        $TSFE->initTemplate();
        $TSFE->determineId();

        $GLOBALS['TSFE'] = $TSFE;
        $this->cObj->start(array(),'');
    }
}

?>
```

Everytime if I execute my task a "404" (frontend-)page without css will be shown. Is there a smart solution for creating frontend URLs for tt_news extension?

System: Typo3 CMS 4.7.7 Introduction Package with RealURL.

Comment: Yes. I'm using the introduction package. I updated my question.

Comment: So follow Krystian's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good solution is to use extension by Dmitry Dulepov called "pagepath".
You can read documentation in this ext - its simple.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I changed the link() function as followed:
`$newsLink = tx_pagepath_api::getPagePath($this->getSingleViewPageId($news['pid']), array('tx_ttnews[tt_news]' => $news['uid']));`

_getSingleViewPageId_ returns the singleView Page ID of the news, which will be stored in the TSConfig.
`public function getSingleViewPageId($newsFolderPageId) {
    $pageTSConfig = t3lib_BEfunc::getPagesTSconfig($newsFolderPageId);
    return @$pageTSConfig['tx_ttnews.']['singlePid'];
}`